# Order methods when inheriting in Ruby

Tags: ruby, inheritance

When using class inheritance, is there a way to order the methods? I want them ordered, because I am inheriting from a class that executes all public methods, in order.

For example:

```
class Foo
  def action_two
    puts "action 2"
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
  def action_one
    puts "action 1"
  end
end

Bar.instance_methods # => [:action_two, :action_one, ...]
```

...and I would like it to return `[:action_one, :action_two, ...]`

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-instance_methods) doesn't say anything about the order and I actually get them in the order you want when I use Ruby 2.1.2. If you want them to come out in a specific order then I think you'll have to do it yourself. You could use the `include_super` parameter to `instance_methods` to get just the current class's methods and then ask [`superclass`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html#method-i-superclass) for its methods:

```
class Bar < Foo
  #...
  def self.instance_methods
    super(false) + superclass.instance_methods
  end
end
```

If you're going to be dealing with `BasicObject` as a possible superclass then you'll want to add a `superclass.nil?` check before calling `superclass.instance_methods`.

If you're inheritance hierarchy is deep then you should be able to put this hackery into the lowest base class (`Foo` in this case) and let the subclasses pick it up through inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do that, you have to define `Bar#action_one` before inheriting `Foo` into `Bar`. Since class inheritance is determined at the creation time of the class that inherits, you cannot do that as is.

A way to overcome this is to make `Foo` a module instead of a class, and include it into `Bar` after `Bar#action_one` is defined.

```
module Foo
  def action_two
    puts "action 2"
  end
end

class Bar
  def action_one
    puts "action 1"
  end
  include Foo
end

Bar.instance_methods
# => [:action_one, :action_two, ...]
```

Comment: What makes you think `instance_methods` returns things in any particular order?

Comment: That's MRI and thus implementation specific. There's nothing I'm aware of in any documentation or specifications that says anything about the order so it could be anything. I don't even see any source traces or links to support your assertion.

Answer (score -1):

```
Bar.ancestors.each_with_object([]) { |a, o| o << a.instance_methods }.flatten.uniq
```

Comment: What makes you think `uniq` will preserve any sort of order?